# Making a prawn table fit with a single header and repeating footer

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I'm generating a PDF with Prawn that has a header on the first page, a repeating footer, and table data throughout.

If I add the table without a bounding box, it starts after the header, but it overlaps the footer.
If I put the table inside a bounding box, it avoids the footer. But to avoid the header, I have to position it below the header and then I lose that space on every subsequent page.

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on prawn's github. It requires you to wrap the table in a bounding box and set the bounding box's start position manually which only affects the first page.

```
  # ... draw your first-page header here
  # Store away the y-position below the header on the first page
  old_y = y
  # Start a bounding box the size of the page (excluding the footer)
  bounding_box([bounds.left, bounds.top],
      :width => bounds.width, :height => bounds.height - FooterHeight) do
    # Restore the old y-position for the first page
    self.y = old_y
    table(...)
  end
```

https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/309